# SharePoint Content DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-database

In SharePoint 2010 and 2013 when does the content DB get created? Is it after you create web application or is it after you create site collection?

In SP2013, since each site collection can have its own URL, we can associate a new content db with each site collection which was not possible in SP2010. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content database gets created when a web application is created. However, there can be more than one content databases in a web application as can be more than one site collection. Each site collection can have a maximum of one database but more than one site collection can share a same content database. This has been the case in MOSS, SP 2010 and is presently also in SP 2013

Comment: Hi you say that each site collection can have a maximum of one database. But what if the size of the content db exceed to a large value and we need to create a new content db for that same site collection. Isnt that supported in SharePoint?

Comment: No you cannot split a site collection to have more than one content database.